How can I point to the screen that other user is sharing in a Teams meeting?
Mostly what the title says, in most meetings one user is presenting something and another different user needs to point to some specific part on the screen for others to see. Even if they are in the same physical room and can point at the physical screen, other remote users wouldn't see it.
I've looked for features like "laser pointer" but it's only for the presenter, who could anyway use the normal mouse pointer for that.
I think I've seen it done before, is it possible in Microsoft Teams? (desktop or web)

The person sharing content can enable annotation mode from the top toolbar.  Once this mode has been enabled, the rest of the meeting participants will be able to access a toolbar that includes a laser pointer option.
See this support article for more information:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-annotation-while-sharing-your-screen-in-microsoft-teams-876ba527-7112-437e-b410-5aec7363c473

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Such feature is not yet available in Teams.
The annotate mode is clumsy because it freezes the presenter screen.
Giving a control is better, but that has downside that other users can also control to presenter's computer and not just point to the screen.
